# What was the experience level of officers during the American Civil war?

Tags: american-civil-war

It's common knowledge that the American Civil War was fought by amateur soldiers.

> **[DISCIPLINE & TRAINING OF SOLDIERS](http://civil-war-officers.leadr.msu.edu/2015/04/15/discipline-training-of-soldiers-2/)**
>   Rather than learning in training camp, Civil War regiments had to learn to fight on the battlefield. The training of regiments was lacking and consisted mainly of the manual of arms, little target practice, company and regimental drills in basic maneuvers and brigade drill and skirmishing tactics. Division drill or mock combat was a rare occurrence. Many regiments went into combat only three weeks after being organized.

.
Before the first Battle of Manassas General McDowell wants more time to prepare his troops **[Lincoln responds](https://slideplayer.com/slide/276522/)**

> It is true that you are green, but they are green also; you are all green together.

My question regards the leadership of those soldiers.

When Abraham Lincoln made his initial call for 75,000 troops April 15, 1861 existing laws required him to rely on states to select and provide those troops to the union.   Congress had not authorized this call up and the Union treasury could not afford it.   So the Union was forced to rely on the States for the troops, supplies, transport and to a large extent leadership of its army.

> **[April 1861-November 1863](https://www.google.com/search?ei=d_wtXqtPjO3mAtP5qOgN&q=April+1861+Ohio+governor+%22embarrassment%22+over+lack+of+military+experience+on+his+staff&oq=April+1861+Ohio+governor+%22embarrassment%22+over+lack+of+military+experience+on+his+staff&gs_l=psy-ab.3...34465.38096..38713...0.0..0.85.156.2......0....1..gws-wiz.h73opNmZpTQ&ved=0ahUKEwjr5ruMk6LnAhWMtlkKHdM8Ct0Q4dUDCAs&uact=5)** Page 9
>   The Ohio Governor spoke of his embarrassment he felt at every step from the lack of practical military experience in his staff, and of his desire to have one on whom he could properly throw the details of military work.

The answer to the Ohio Governor's request for anybody with military experience was General **[George McClellan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_B._McClellan)** a 1846 graduate of the Military Academy, who was 19 when the Mexican-American War began and 21 when it ended.  McClellan had risen to the rank of Captain before resigning his commission in Jan 16, 1857.  McClellan would go from Captain in 46, to the Civilian president of a railroad 60 to major general in the Union Army 1861, where he out ranked all but 75 year old, Lt. **[General Winfield Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winfield_Scott)** in May of 1861 at the age of 34.

**[Ulysses S. Grant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_S._Grant)** graduated from West Point in 1843,  was a logistics officer at 23 years old when the Mexican-American War began and saw some limited action before it ended.  Grant who resigned his commission as a Captain, July 31, 1854 for being drunk on duty.  He would end the Civil War in command of all Union Forces but in April 1861, when Lincoln called up his first 75,000 troops was working for his younger brother in the family leather goods business.

Two of the most famous and accomplished Southern cavalry offices of the American Civil War were **[General Nathan Bedford Forrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_Bedford_Forrest)** and **[Colonel John Mosby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_S._Mosby)**, both of whom started the civil war as enlisted men with no military experience.

> **My Question:**
>   What was the experience level of officers during the American Civil war?

---

**From Comments**

> **Gort the Robot:**
>   There are lots of big civil war names with that experience In particular, two you mention, McClellan and Grant, saw real combat experience there. So did Robert E. Lee.

McClellan was 19 when the Mexican American war began( Apr 25, 1846) and 21 when it concluded.  He did see "real" combat there, but would you really call him experienced general to lead all of your nations armed forces based upon experience he had when 21 years old?

Grant too saw "real" combat in the Mexican American war.  He got into a few calvary charges.  But he was still a logistics officer for most of that war. 23 when that war began.  Hardly the kind of experience one would claim in making one an experienced General of the Armies.

Comment: There are lots of [big civil war names with that experience](https://www.thoughtco.com/generals-who-served-mexican-american-war-2136198)   In particular, two you mention, McClellan and Grant, saw real combat experience there.  So did Robert E. Lee.

Comment: Grant’s autobiography is well written and well worth reading.

Comment: _"McClellan a 1946 graduate of the Military Academy"_  you may have a typo there, unless he had invented time travel.

Comment: Please, please don't muddy questions and answers with comments!  It makes them far less useful.  Just make adjustments based on comments, and if you want to explain directly, use a comment.  Remember, this is supposed to be about preserving interesting questions and their answers, not about preserving a debate for posterity.  In 2050, someone might care about the military experience of Civil War veterans, but no one will give a damn what "Gort the Robot" said.

Comment: @GorttheRobot   As comments are not for conversations,  I always try to address comments at the end of my answer.   I feel any comment worthy of being answered is worthy of being included in the answer, as it's probable addresses observations which others have.  This is the practice of others on this board and was suggested to me by others.  If you would like to change that take it up with the mods..

Comment: I agree that addressing comments is good, and belongs there.  I don't think it should be handled as a call-response type thing.  It makes things much less readable.  For instance, as it stands, discussion of Grant and McClellan is scattered through the question.  It would be more clear if the same information about each man was centralized in one spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [June 24, 1861](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Gazetteer/Places/America/United_States/Army/USMA/Cullums_Register/Classes/1861Jun24.html) Graduating class of West point was 34 in number. That is barely sufficient for just one of the [8 company, 400 man, infantry regiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Army#Formation) of the Civil War Union Army. Even assuming that a full 40 years of graduates were available that would be barely cover the unit needs of 40 regiments, or 40 * 400 = 16,000 men. That is but one eleventh of the officer needs for the 175,000 men at [Gettysburg in July 1863](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Gettysburg).

[image]

Add on that the officers were split between two warring sides of a few hundred thousand men each, that suffered extensive casualties and had additional staff officer requirements, and one would not be far off to say that the officer corps for both sides was, for practical purposes, nearly 100% amateur. Further, even at the end of the War it is likely that few of the officers had even a full three years experience either in uniform or in combat tour.

By way of comparison, the American Civil War is not even as long as the [War of the First Coalition, 1792-1797](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_First_Coalition). That latter saw the recognition of numerous future French military leaders, foremost among them Napoleon, yet most if not all of the future Marshals of France were yet to be promoted past Brigadier General.

Comment: That's true of junior officers, but many senior officers in the American Civil War [saw action in the Mexican American War](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=civil+war+officers+from+mexican-american+war&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: @GorttheRobot: Both sides were still limited to sharing the same pool of roughly 1300 officers with prior experience. A tiny fraction of what was required to properly lead the forces being fielded.

Comment: Still, I think given that the OP mentions Grant and McClellan, it's worth noting that both saw real combat.

Comment: @GorttheRobot  Yes both saw "real" combat.   McClellan was 19 when the Mexican American War began, and Grant was 23...   That doesn't make either experienced to be the commander of all Union Forces..

Comment: I'm not sure why you put "real" in quotes given that both men were under fire and Grant led men under fire.

Comment: That wasn't done by Pieter.

Comment: I rolled back to the original question.

Comment: Note to others: If you are making a wholesale change to the tone of the question, it is more appropriate to create your own answer rather than make it appear as if the original answerer said something they did not.

Comment: @GorttheRobot: This OP often makes extensive edits of his questions and answers. I suspect that an inadvertent error was made with this edit of my answer. Thank you for restoring everything on each side.

Comment: Yeah, looking back I suspect a cut-and-paste into the wrong box.

Comment: OK, thanks Pieter, I was really confused. I'd like to point out that confining your point of reference to the graduating class of 1861 is IMO a short sighted point of reference.   The graduating classes of 1855-1860 would also have provided some of the junior officers, and the earlier classes some (company and battalion) commanders and staff officers ... and there was still the need to have officers on the frontier .... though of course a lot of regiments were raised by the states and had few if any regulars at all ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Making the assumption that the graduating class of 1861 was *at least as large as the **average** graduating class over the previous 40 years* was my point. The point is that at every level, from commander in chief to brigade staff to platoon level the deficit of trained and experienced officers was profound, nearly overwhelming. Perfect example of the Peter Principle at work, with nearly everyone having been promoted far above their competence.

Comment: Pieter: same problem with the mobilization for WW II, except the army wasn't cut in half.  The rapid expansion/mobilizatio was on a similar order of magnitude.  It is only since WW II that a large standing army has become the norm.  Every war before that began with a small Army that had to baloon up in a hurry.

Comment: *with nearly everyone having been promoted far above their competence* and positions being open to talent.  You are painting a "glass half full" picture.  Custer got his stars, breveted of course, because he was found to be, on the battlefield, an effective and bold leader.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Wonderful! With a population in 1860 (Union & Confederate, white only) equal to France in 1789 it turned up, in 4 years of war, a Grouchy. But nary a LaSalle, Murat, Kellerman (pere or fils), Montbrun, Pajol, Subervie or Excelmans to be found anywhere. To be fair, Jeb Stuart might also be termed an incompetent Murat. Bedford Forest is certainly no Jean Lannes, though he seems to have been competent.

Comment: W.T. Sherman was as good as any of the ones you named. (But he was a West Pointer). Joshua Chamberlain rose from being a leader among volunteers to a competent regular army officer. So did many others. But quality control was, as your answer suggests, uneven at best. (IIRC, our Mil History prof was sure that loss of Davout hurt Napoleon worse than losing a corps ... but that might have been hyperbole)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Yes, Sherman and Grant both turned up - perhaps Soult quality, but Lannes rose from simple Grenadier so I think Bedford Forest the best comparison. The point is that by the mid 1790's nearly every French brigade is well led - and that never happened for either the Union or the Confederates. One might liken McLennan to Berthier I suppose - valuable on staff but incompetent in command.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: As for Davout - read up on Auerstadt. Your professor might have **understated** Davou's value. Davout was a true **tactical** mastermind, which perfectly complemented Napoleon's **operational** brilliance.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Fair points all, and I think we are getting a bit chatty, so I'll say "thanks" for clearing up my confusion.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Trained Officers averaged approximately 1 per regiment**

I know I'm answering an old post with an already-accepted answer, but there was only one and it missed out on a key feature of the War: Military colleges. The US didn't just have West Point for trained army officers. In the United States before the war, especially in the South, there was a sense that a fight was coming.  In the 1840s numerous state military colleges were established which provided students a military education  roughly on par with West Point. I say roughly because for the most part West Point did (and still does) focus on engineering, so a graduate of a State military school like VMI might get the same infantry/artillery/cavalry training as a West Point grad, but by and large missed out on the Civil and Military engineering aspects.

In "[Seed Corn of the Confederacy](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Seed_Corn_of_the_Confederacy.html?id=gdJ2AAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)" by James Gindlesperger it's stated that at the start of the war trained officers (those that graduated a military college of any sort or had served as an officer in the US Army or foreign army) averaged about 1 per 1000 men. As a Civil war regiment nominally contained 1000 men (though in reality as they weren't reinforced 400 was closer to an accurate average size) you get about 1-2 trained soldiers per regiment.  At the start of the war this number favored the south, as their more numerous military colleges provided a larger pool of nominally-trained officers.  For example the famed "Stonewall Brigade" at 1st Manassas had a high number of VMI graduates as officers (IIRC something like 30% of the officers captain and above were VMI grads but I'm away from my books so don't take that as gospel).  That'd be about 4x the "normal" amount of trained officers in the unit.  As the war progressed those numbers evened out as officers were killed and both sides had a crash-course in officer training.

Of course, knowing the proper evolution for company or regimental drill (something you could expect to learn at a military college) and knowing how to run a brigade/division/corps/army are two wildly different things.  There were exactly 0 divisions in the US Army when the South seceded.  There weren't even brigades, army organization ended at the regiment.  Prior to that the Mexican-American war in the 1840s saw the US field an army of 79,000 men.  But considering the senior officers on both sides (Lee, Grant, Longstreet, etc) were mostly junior officers and none, IIRC, commanded more than a regiment during that war, the experience of anyone in command of a brigade or higher during the Civil War was nil, and it was all learned more-or-less on the job.

Comment: Never apologize for contributing an actually useful answer - even to a question already having an accepted answer.